# struts2 ognl servlet context

Tags: struts2, ognl

I have some constants like APPVERSION, APPNAME and APPREV that I want to display on every page on my Struts 2 app.

With these requirements I thought that it would be great to put that info intro servletContext and to load this when the app is deployed.

I have created a listener that implements `ServletContextListener`:

```java
public class ApplicationInitListenerImpl extends GenericVsService implements ApplicationInitListener,ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        ServletContext sc = sce.getServletContext();        
        sc.setAttribute("appVer",xxx.utils.VConstants.APPVER);
        sc.setAttribute("appName",xxx.utils.VConstants.APPNAME);       
        sc.setAttribute("appRev",xxx.utils.VConstants.APPREV);
    }   
}
```

and then I have added in my `web.xml` the listener:

```xml
<listener>
        <listener-class>xxx.listeners.ApplicationInitListenerImpl</listener-class>
</listener>
```

In my Tiles template I have added:

```xml
<s:property value="#application.appName"/> - <s:property value="#application.appVer"/>
```

But I get nothing here.

If I retrieve the servletContext from a Struts 2 Action I can read the correct values, so the values are set ok.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I thought this should work; using `#attr` should search all the scopes (as will using JSP EL, `${appName}`).

Comment: If that works both are a lot easier than what I would have thought of first... `<s:property value="@com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext@getContext().application['appName']"/>` of course this requires static method invocation be enabled... This would do what had been working in the action directly from the jsp.

Comment: Hi Dave, it seems that #attr works as expected. What i don`t understand is why did this not worked with #application. ServletContext is not equivalent with application scope ? ps submit that as a answer so that i can approve it.

Comment: @DaveNewton if you get a moment it would be interesting to know why it doesn't work. I would have thought #application should be equivalent to @com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext@getContext().application

Comment: Why the down vote? The OP did some work that is a good example for others and the initial technique tried was logical but didn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<s:property value="#attr.appName"/> - <s:property value="#attr.appVer"/>
```

Or

```
${appName}  -  ${appVer}
```